# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=tel:xxxxx }

Tags: android, exception

I met a problem
But I don't know where the problem is
This is my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"phonenumber" ));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.format("tel:%s", phonenumber)));
startActivity(in);
```

Comment: thanks for you help.But I want to know why this happened.I think my code is ok,but it really happened.

Comment: Are you sure you used the phone number variable or "phonenumber" as a string value. This is why I suggested the String.format as opposed to string concatenation. ACTION_VIEW should be fine, so the only possible point of failure is the URI